# how send more item details to cart Api in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api

this is postman api call

> `http://praveen/Magento/rest/V1/carts/1/items`

**Responce is**

`{
        "item_id": 10,
        "sku": "lenovo",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "lenovo",
        "price": 35000,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "1"
    },`

Here am trying to more information in product information like `new_field` from database how to get it,Thank You in Advance.[image]

Comment: You should try extension attributes

Comment: Thank you for response, am getting image url by extension attributes, but i'm not getting data from database or additional item information column into cart item in API

Comment: for this you need to create setter getter of new fields by extending CartInterface of Quote module.